# accessing hosts across multiple networks within a home network with 3 routers

Tags: routing, wireless-router

At home I have multiple routers:

1. router1 (icotera i4850) connected to the modem/internet, network is 192.168.3.1.
2. router2 (TP-Link WR841N) connected to router1, its network address is 192.168.4.1 and hosts in the network are 192.168.4.2-254
3. router3 (TP-Link WR841N) connected to router1, its network address is 192.168.5.1 and hosts in the network are 192.168.5.2-254.

I want to establish HTTP connections from 192.168.4.X to 192.168.5.Y, obviously via router1.  I can't quite figure out what can I configure on icotera i4850 (router1), but on routers 2 and 3 I found Advanced Routing/Static Route List.

TP-Link routers are cheap and seem to be more flexible than the icotera one. In theory I could add a 4th TP-link router and connect it to the router1 on upstream side and router2/3 as downstream TP-Link routers. TP-link routers support 4 modes: Wireless router (default), WISP, Access Point and Range extender.

Thanks!

[image: icotera i4850 admin UI]

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and have configured port forwarding: I've taken router4(192.168.6.1) and connected as following:

router1 <- router4 <- (router2 as 192.168.6.2,router3  as 192.168.6.3)

router4:123=router2/192.168.4.123

router4:125=router3/192.168.5.125

this way 192.168.5.125 can access 192.168.4.123:80 as 192.168.6.2:123.